# Not Authorized to View This Page

Tags: wordpress, ssl-certificate, hosting

Can someone help when visited in https the error stated that "Not Authorized to View This Page [CFN #0004]" but in Http the site load or work without having an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Reset the URLs to their http version. You can do this via PHPMYADMIN in the `wp_options` table by locating `wp_home` and `wp_siteurl` and adding the http:// version of your website or by adding constants in wp-config.php:

> Add these two lines to your wp-config.php, where “example.com” is the correct location of your site.
>
> define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
>
> define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );

**Reference:** https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/#edit-wp-config-php

The latter is probably the easiest.

To make your site use https, you must FIRST install a valid SSL certificate. Contact your host for assistance with this.

**Credit:** https://wordpress.org/support/topic/http-to-https-website-crash/

Answer (score 0):

Move your site from the public folder in your FTP to the **secure** folder. This will fix the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).